# How to loop all class variables with key and value

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, foreach

I'm making an Save Version checker and if version doesn't match transport old variable values into new.

I have this class

```cs
[System.Serializable]
public class SavePattern
{
    public int SaveVersion = 1;
    public string Name;
    public int Electricity;
    public string[] Inventory;
}
```

I want to loop all public variables of class and be able to use it like key and value variable.

Comment: What purpose? Your dictionary would be string and object which would require a cast of the value. You could explain what you have and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can loop your class variable by **`using System.Reflection;`**

```
SavePattern savePatt = new SavePattern();
PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(SavePattern).GetProperties();

foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    var val = property.GetValue(savePatt);
}
```